# Organize itens from txt file in a list

Tags: python

starting from a txt file as an input file, I need to organize the lines in a list that must contain the same characteristics.

Given a txt file with these lines:

```
SimulationControl,
    Yes,                     !- Do Zone Sizing Calculation
    Yes,                     !- Do System Sizing Calculation

Building,
    Building,                !- Name
    0,                       !- North Axis {deg}
    Suburbs,                 !- Terrain
    0.04,                    !- Loads Convergence Tolerance Value {W}

SizingPeriod:DesignDay,
    Summer Design Day in Modelagem WoodFrame (01-01:02-01) Dec,  !- Name
    1,                       !- Month
    15,                      !- Day of Month
    SummerDesignDay,         !- Day Type

SizingPeriod:DesignDay,
    Winter Design Day in Modelagem WoodFrame (01-01:02-01),  !- Name
    6,                       !- Month
    15,                      !- Day of Month
```

I need a lists whit:

```
building = [

Building,
    Building,                !- Name
    0,                       !- North Axis {deg}
    Suburbs,                 !- Terrain
    0.04,                    !- Loads Convergence Tolerance Value {W}

]
```

```
sizingperiod = [

SizingPeriod:DesignDay,
    Summer Design Day in Modelagem WoodFrame (01-01:02-01) Dec,  !- Name
    1,                       !- Month
    15,                      !- Day of Month
    SummerDesignDay,         !- Day Type

SizingPeriod:DesignDay,
    Winter Design Day in Modelagem WoodFrame (01-01:02-01),  !- Name
    6,                       !- Month
    15,                      !- Day of Month

]
```

```
simulation = [

SimulationControl,
    Yes,                     !- Do Zone Sizing Calculation
    Yes,                     !- Do System Sizing Calculation

]
```

The txt is not ordered.

I try to organize the lines whit a start and end strings but in some cases that not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a site for specific questions, but this isn't a question and it's not very specific; that is, it's not clear what exactly you need help with, especially since the result you're showing here isn't valid Python data. Please read [ask].

Comment: Are your results lists of strings?  Are you potentially looking for a yaml parser?

Answer (score 1):

Sure – this'll get you a dict of lists of blocks of lists of lines:

```
import io
from collections import defaultdict

txt_file = io.StringIO("""
SimulationControl,
    Yes,                     !- Do Zone Sizing Calculation
    Yes,                     !- Do System Sizing Calculation

Building,
    Building,                !- Name
    0,                       !- North Axis {deg}
    Suburbs,                 !- Terrain
    0.04,                    !- Loads Convergence Tolerance Value {W}

SizingPeriod:DesignDay,
    Summer Design Day in Modelagem WoodFrame (01-01:02-01) Dec,  !- Name
    1,                       !- Month
    15,                      !- Day of Month
    SummerDesignDay,         !- Day Type

SizingPeriod:DesignDay,
    Winter Design Day in Modelagem WoodFrame (01-01:02-01),  !- Name
    6,                       !- Month
    15,                      !- Day of Month
""")

parsed = defaultdict(list)
current_key = None
current_entry = None

for line in txt_file:
    if line.strip() == "":
        continue
    if line.startswith(" "):
        current_entry.append(line)
    else:
        current_key = line.strip()
        current_entry = []
        parsed[current_key].append(current_entry)

print(dict(parsed))
```

(naturally `txt_file` would be your `open("my_file.txt")`)

and the output is (nicely formatted for viewing here)

```
{
    "Building,": [
        [
            "    Building,                !- Name\n",
            "    0,                       !- North Axis {deg}\n",
            "    Suburbs,                 !- Terrain\n",
            "    0.04,                    !- Loads Convergence Tolerance Value {W}\n",
        ]
    ],
    "SimulationControl,": [
        [
            "    Yes,                     !- Do Zone Sizing Calculation\n",
            "    Yes,                     !- Do System Sizing Calculation\n",
        ]
    ],
    "SizingPeriod:DesignDay,": [
        [
            "    Summer Design Day in Modelagem WoodFrame (01-01:02-01) Dec,  !- Name\n",
            "    1,                       !- Month\n",
            "    15,                      !- Day of Month\n",
            "    SummerDesignDay,         !- Day Type\n",
        ],
        [
            "    Winter Design Day in Modelagem WoodFrame (01-01:02-01),  !- Name\n",
            "    6,                       !- Month\n",
            "    15,                      !- Day of Month\n",
        ],
    ],
}
```

Comment: Was going to submit basically the same answer but you cover it with this one. One wrinkle is that I think you should use `current_entry = [current_key]` to get the first line in the output as I think that is what the OP wanted.